# How to extract the text 8 from the 2nd row and 2nd column as per the html through Selenium and VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriver

Using selenium vba i want 2nd row and 2nd column value from webpage table below is the code which i have try but it capture all table.

The output which i want is 8.

```html
driver.FindElementByXPath("//table[contains(@class,'zedoLocTable')]").text
```

Please find the below html code.

```html
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div id="localityTiers">
<br><br>
<table class="zedoLocTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>TYPE</th>
<th>TIER</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Resedential Sale</b>
</td><td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>Resedential Rent</b>
</td><td>5</td>
</tr><tr>
<td><b>Commercial Sale</b>
</td><td>1</td>
</tr><tr>
<td><b>Commercial Lease</b>
</td><td>1</td>
</tr></tbody></table><table></table></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Below is the table pic

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to extract the text **8** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='zedoLocTable']//tr/td/b[contains(.,'Resedential Sale')]//following::td[1]").text
```

Comment: Hi New contributor & Moshe Slavin thanks for the reply,@New contributor your code is working fine!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a faster CSS selector, than using xPath, if you are working with later IE or other browers apart from IE

```
Debug.Print driver.FindElementByCSS(".zedoLocTable td + td").innerText
```

[image]